# Purpose of "myPlugin_dialog.py" file created by QGIS Plugin Builder

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qt4, pyqt

I usually use QGIS Plugin Builder to create working templates for QGIS plugins.

While a generic Python plugin needs the files below;

---

```
__init__.py
metadata.txt
resources.py (translated from resources.rcc via pyrcc4)
myPlugin.py
myPlugin_UI.py (translated from myPlugin_UI.ui via pyuic4)
```

---

Plugin Builder also creates the following file;

---

```
myPlugin_dialog.py
```

---

I can understand and use it but **why do we need this file myPlugin_dialog.py**?

If I import "myPlugin_UI.py" at the beginning, **I can already access and interact with the form objects directly from the main module** "myPlugin.py"

Why should I need an additional file? **What is the advantage of this structure?**

(Please explain in basic word since I am not fully fluent with PyQt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically the only files you need for a plugin are:

```
__init__.py
metadata.txt
plugin.py
```

All the other files are just extra stuff depending on what you plugin does.  If you don't need any resources (which you normally do) then you don't need `resources.rc`.

On to your question:

`myPlugin_dialog.py`

Just hold a class that inherits from your generated ui files.  This is just normal Python inheritance and means you can extend the generated code with more logic if needed.

```
from myPlugin_UI import dialogUI


class MyDialog(dialogUI, QDialog):
   def __init__(self, parent):
       ....

   def dosomething(self):
       self.label.hide()


dlg = MyDialog()
dlg.dosomething()
```

You don't need to have this class however if you need to add extra logic to the widget/dialog then this is the preferred method.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. I also found a similar explanation that says; "...The whole point of this class is to abstract the the setup of the UI so we don’t have to deal with GUI setup in our main Python module."